# why in JS 'this' keyword points to global variable, when i use function alias stored in another variable ? Code is Given Below

Tags: javascript

**Here is my code showing that "var B" is targeting a global variable:**

```js
function koo(){
  console.log( this.B );
 }

 var sampleObj = {
   B: 2,
   koo: koo
 };

 var xyz = sampleObj.koo;
 
 var B = "It's global";
 xyz();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197480/why-does-x-defined-inside-a-function-become-a-global-variable-when-i-didnt-de?rq=1

Comment: it's not a using scoping .why all you sent these kind of links ?

Comment: Guys, don't mistake scope with binding. They're two completely different things.

Comment: Because JavaScript doesn't autobind properties. `sampleObj.koo` returns the exact same value you assigned to it: `xyz === koo`. If you want it to behave different you need to bind the function yourself: `var xyz = sampleObj.koo.bind(sampleObj);` or simply `var xyz = koo.bind(sampleObj);`.

Comment: `this` will be the space to the left of the right-most dot upon calling. if nothing else, global.

Answer (score 0):

you are not executing it like `sampleObj.koo()`, and taking a direct reference to `xyz` so it is impossible to know from where it taken from, it cab be associated with so many object (or even not to anyone) with the same reference. if you want to invoke some function (reference you have) from outside in the monitor of a object, try calling `xyz.call(sampleObj)` instead

Comment: ok. then what about i use function that invoke (koo) ?

Comment: so where is `koo` actually as "koo"? inside `sampleObj` right? then call it like `sampleObj.koo()`, if you take a reference of `koo` and want to execute directly it will never remember the scope. I hope it will help :)